# Is it possible to create an Azure Cognitive Search index from a json file?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'd like to create an index that's based on a rather complex JSON file.  Is there a way to have Azure Cognitive Search parse the file and create an appropriate index for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this using the 'Import Data' workflow in Azure Cognitive Search using the Azure portal.  You can find more details on what type of json files and json objects are supported here: [Importing JSON files with Cognitive Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-json-blobs#:%7E:text=Parsing%20modes%20%20%20%20parsingMode%20%20,mode%20if%20your%20blobs%20consist%20o%20...%20)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your JSON file contains data records. If you want a more programmatic approach you can find one example record in your JSON. Copy this and in Visual Studio use [Edit -> Paste Special](https://medium.com/@coffmans/paste-json-xml-as-classes-in-visual-studio-66e67e60be44) to create a class that represents your record.

[image]

Then you simply instantiate objects using your new type and you submit them to the index using the SDK as normal.